# wkhtmltopdf Rotativa Blazor not workin in deploy IIS

Tags: iis, blazor-server-side, wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to generate PDF.

When debugging with blazor it works fine, but when I publish it on IIS, when it goes to open the PDF page an error appears:
**Error
Failed to load PDF document.**

How can I solve?

**Resolved**

Solved, thanks everyone for your advice. I found the problem, it generated the file with a different source path.

Comment: The PDF that you are trying to open, is it already on the server, or are you uploading & opening it?

Comment: @tgolisch The pdf I am creating on the server and I am opening it.
I think it's a virtual preview, because I can't find any generated files inside. Am I wrong something?

Comment: First, please check if the `application/pdf` type has been added to your MIME type, then make sure that IIS_IUSRS has the permission to read and write the pdf file.

Comment: I saw another article that said you might see this  problem if you don't have "msvcp140.dll" and "vcruntime140.dll" in the c:\windows\SysWOW64\ folder on your server.  I think those are part of VC runtime and get installed with VStudio or Blazor.

Comment: Hi, @parente89. Glad to hear your problem is solved. Please, consider writing your solution as an answer to your own post, and then mark it as an answer, better than edit the original post. This approach will help other users to fastly identify that this post is already answered and resolved. Thanks for sharing!